# Para quê serve o IS em Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um curso de python e não consegui entender o operador binário IS.

Comment: Is verifica se é o mesmo objeto... muita gente confunfe com o == que verifica se possui o mesmo valor.

Comment: Então o IS é como se fosse uma pergunta né?

Comment: Na real ele verifica se dois obejtos possuem o mesmo ID... se possuirem retorna True.